# Call public method from Form Collection Question

Tags: c#, winforms

I am hiding and showing forms through Form Collection as a user timeout feature and need to call a public method in each form as I am showing it again to update the form with the logged in user (in the event it changes).

I am, however, having issue with this as it does not seem that I am able to do this direct from the iteration of the form collection.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Here is the code that I am working off of.  Any help is very much appreciated!

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
  if (frm.Visible == false && frm.Name != "FStart" && frm.Name != "FMain")
  {
     //Here I would like to call frm.UpdateUser(.....);
     frm.Show();
  }
}
```

I appreciate everyone's help.  The method is a public void in each form.

I've tried to access the public method from the form collection and I've tried to access the method directly.

Answer (score 0):

The first potential issue in your code is that you are iterating the `Application.OpenForms` collection in hopes of finding instances where `Visible==false`. However, the `Application.OpenForms` won't contain forms that have never been visible and (depending on the method of closure) may not contain forms that are subsequently hidden. Since your first loop condition may evaluate to `false`, the `frm.Show()` line is not guaranteed to execute.

One solution would be to make your own collection of Forms and iterate that instead.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Mixed list of Form references where "some" will implement `UpdateUser`
    /// </summary>
    List<Form> AllForms = new List<Form>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        AllForms.Add(this);
        AllForms.Add(new UserFormA());
        AllForms.Add(new UserFormB());
    }
}
```

The second issue is that your syntax tells the compiler to interpret the loop object as a `Form` in your loop `foreach (Form frm in fc)...` however the `Form` class itself doesn't have a `UserUpdate` method. Before the `UpdateUser` method can be called we need to ascertain that the specific inherited class in your collection is one that supports the `UpdateUser` method and one of the more robust ways to do this is make an interface (we can call it `IUpdatableUserForm`) and choose which of your inherited `Form` classes will implement it. For example:

```
interface IUpdatableUserForm
{
    void UpdateUser();
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool Visible { get; set; }
    public void Show(IWin32Window owner);
}
public class UserFormA : Form, IUpdatableUserForm
{
    public UserFormA()
    {
        Name = nameof(UserFormA);
    }
    public void UpdateUser()
    {
        Size = new Size(500, 300);
        Text = Name;
    }
}
```

Now, as you iterate the collection on Form you can ensure that a *particular* inherited Form implements the UpdateUser method using the `is` operator and only call the method if it is present. (By way of comparison, the `dynamic` keyword will throw an exception if it encounters a derivative of `Form` that does not implement `UpdateUser`).

```
private void onTest()
{
    foreach (Form frm in AllForms)
    {
        if (frm is IUpdatableUserForm safeForm)
        {
            if (!safeForm.Visible)
            {
                switch (safeForm.Name)
                {
                    case "FStart":
                    case "FMain":
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Here I would like to call frm.UpdateUser(.....);
                        safeForm.UpdateUser();
                        safeForm.Show(this);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a good answer, covers all the problems, and provides a correct solution. The only thing I would add is-- maybe OP should consider publishing an event (e.g. `OnUpdateUser`) and having the relevant forms subscribe to it. I think that would be more idiomatic to WinForms, and this whole mess would no longer be needed at all.

Comment: The statement at the beginning is wrong: `Application.OpenForms` can contain forms with `Visible == false` for forms that were visible once and are hidden with `Hide` instead of `Close`

Comment: @NineBerry thx I'll get that corrected.

Comment: @m-lyons10 my intent was to address your code as presented and question as asked and hopefully assist in getting something working as a first pass. That said, I want to _resoundingly agree_ with John Wu that firing a simple event (if you're familiar with doing that or ready to take it on) offers a _way_ more optimal solution that will surely make your code cleaner and life easier because the need for iterating a collection of any type simply goes away.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [dynamic keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) to access the method, `UpdateUser`. Here is an example:

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (dynamic frm in fc)
{
    if (frm.Name != "FStart" && frm.Name != "FMain")
    {
       frm.UpdateUser(); //You will still have to add the arguments....
       frm.Show();
    }
 }
```

Just remember that when you use the `dynamic` keyword, it does not care what methods you try to call, or the arguments you supply to them, so just be careful when using it.